# How do I override the [] operator as in list[1:10]?

Tags: python, list

How can I implement a customized list so that I can override the implementation of `list[a:b]`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your problem is not knowing the word for it. You need an __indexer__ . See [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

Comment: Related link: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames

Answer (score 5):

Implement the [`__getitem__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__); in case of a slice a [`slice` object](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices) is passed in.

A simple version could be:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if isinstance(index, slice):
        return [self[i] for i in range(*slice.indices(len(self)))]
    return self._internal_sequence[index]
```

Note that for slice assignment and slice deletion you must also implement the [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) and [`__delitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) hooks.

When overriding existing container types, you'll also have to handle the [`__getslice__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__); it is deprecated but Python 2 types still implement it. Again, there are corresponding [`__setslice__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setslice__) and [`__delslice__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delslice__) hooks for slice assignment and deletion too.

Answer (score 0):

Define the [`__*item__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) methods to customize indexing.